# removing dynamically generated element using addeventlistener

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i´m trying to add an `eventlistener` to a **dynamically generated element**. The listener is supposed to be for the **button** of the generated div. Every button has a unique `id`, based on the value entered in the input field.
Everything is working fine, but the `eventlistener` doesn´t.

Here is the code:

```js
function updateList() {

    let listItem = new Object();
    listItem.name = document.getElementById('userListItem').value;

    if (listItem.name.length >= 1) {

        let timeWhenAdded = new Date();
        listItem.timeStamp = `${timeWhenAdded.getDate()}.${timeWhenAdded.getMonth()+1}.${timeWhenAdded.getFullYear()}, 
        at ${timeWhenAdded.getHours()}:${timeWhenAdded.getMinutes()} Uhr`;

        let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.className = 'Item';
        newDiv.id = `${listItem.name}Item`;

        let itemHeading = document.createElement('h2');

        let itemDescription = document.createElement('p');

        let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
        deleteButton.id = `${listItem.name}RemoveItemButton`;
        deleteButton.className = `DeleteButton`;

        newDiv.append(itemHeading, itemDescription, deleteButton);

        let itemContent = document.createTextNode(listItem.name);
        itemHeading.appendChild(itemContent);
        
        let itemtime = document.createTextNode(`Added on: ${listItem.timeStamp}`)
        itemDescription.appendChild(itemtime);

        let itemRemover = document.createTextNode('remove');
        deleteButton.appendChild(itemRemover);

        let bucketListDiv = document.getElementById('bucket-list');
        bucketListDiv.appendChild(newDiv);

        document.getElementById('userListItem').value = "";
    } else {
        alert('Type an item in the input-field');
    }
}

let ItemButton = document.getElementsByClassName('Item');
$(document).on('click', ItemButton, function() {
    console.log('clicked button');
});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>This is a list</h1>
      <div class="userinput">
          <input type="text" id="userListItem">
          <button id="addButton" onclick="updateList()">add</button>
      </div>
      <div id="bucket-list"></div>
</body>
```

The `RemoveItemButton` is supposed to delete the whole generated `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target the element you click on instead.

```js
function updateList() {

    let listItem = new Object();
    listItem.name = document.getElementById('userListItem').value;

    if (listItem.name.length >= 1) {

        let timeWhenAdded = new Date();
        listItem.timeStamp = `${timeWhenAdded.getDate()}.${timeWhenAdded.getMonth()+1}.${timeWhenAdded.getFullYear()}, 
        at ${timeWhenAdded.getHours()}:${timeWhenAdded.getMinutes()} Uhr`;

        let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.className = 'Item';
        newDiv.id = `${listItem.name}Item`;

        let itemHeading = document.createElement('h2');

        let itemDescription = document.createElement('p');

        let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
        deleteButton.id = `${listItem.name}RemoveItemButton`;
        deleteButton.className = `DeleteButton`;

        newDiv.append(itemHeading, itemDescription, deleteButton);

        let itemContent = document.createTextNode(listItem.name);
        itemHeading.appendChild(itemContent);
        
        let itemtime = document.createTextNode(`Added on: ${listItem.timeStamp}`)
        itemDescription.appendChild(itemtime);

        let itemRemover = document.createTextNode('remove');
        deleteButton.appendChild(itemRemover);

        let bucketListDiv = document.getElementById('bucket-list');
        bucketListDiv.appendChild(newDiv);

        document.getElementById('userListItem').value = "";
    } else {
        alert('Type an item in the input-field');
    }
}

$(document).on('click', '.DeleteButton', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>This is a list</h1>
      <div class="userinput">
          <input type="text" id="userListItem">
          <button id="addButton" onclick="updateList()">add</button>
      </div>
      <div id="bucket-list"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example using vanilla JavaScript:

```js
document
.getElementById('bucket-list')
.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  const btn = target.closest('.DeleteButton');
  if (!btn) return;
  btn.parentElement.remove();
});

function updateList() {
    let listItem = {}; // just use an object literal!
    listItem.name = document.getElementById('userListItem').value;

    if (listItem.name.length >= 1) {
        let timeWhenAdded = new Date();
        listItem.timeStamp = `${timeWhenAdded.getDate()}.${timeWhenAdded.getMonth()+1}.${timeWhenAdded.getFullYear()}, 
        at ${timeWhenAdded.getHours()}:${timeWhenAdded.getMinutes()} Uhr`;

        let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.className = 'Item';
        newDiv.id = `${listItem.name}Item`;

        let itemHeading = document.createElement('h2');

        let itemDescription = document.createElement('p');

        let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
        deleteButton.id = `${listItem.name}RemoveItemButton`;
        deleteButton.className = `DeleteButton`;

        newDiv.append(itemHeading, itemDescription, deleteButton);

        let itemContent = document.createTextNode(listItem.name);
        itemHeading.appendChild(itemContent);
        
        let itemtime = document.createTextNode(`Added on: ${listItem.timeStamp}`)
        itemDescription.appendChild(itemtime);

        let itemRemover = document.createTextNode('remove');
        deleteButton.appendChild(itemRemover);

        let bucketListDiv = document.getElementById('bucket-list');
        bucketListDiv.appendChild(newDiv);

        document.getElementById('userListItem').value = "";
    } else {
        alert('Type an item in the input-field');
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>This is a list</h1>
      <div class="userinput">
          <input type="text" id="userListItem">
          <button id="addButton" onclick="updateList()">add</button>
      </div>
      <div id="bucket-list"></div>
</body>
```